# Rendering an object stored in state

Tags: ajax, reactjs, google-api

I'm trying to render out my calendar's event summaries, using a .map function. I've stored my calendar events object in state, but can't find a way to .map out the different event summaries. Any suggestions?

```
        export default class Container extends React.Component{
          calendarID="xxx"
          apiKey="zzz";

          state = { events: [] };
          setEvents = (a) => {
            this.setState(a);
          }
          componentDidMount() {
                    ajax.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${this.calendarID}/events?fields=items(summary,id,location,start)&key=${this.apiKey}`)
              .end((error, response) => {
                if(!error && response ) {
                  this.setEvents({events: response.body});
                  console.log("success");
                  console.log(this.state.events);
                } else {
                  console.log("Errors: ", error);
                }
              });
          }
          render(){
            let lista = this.state.events;
            let arr = Object.keys(lista).map(key => lista[key])
            return (
              <div class = "container">
                  {arr.map((event, index) => {
                    const summary = event.summary;
                    return (<div key={index}>{summary}</div>);
                  })}
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
```

EDIT:
Thanks for your answers! This is the data that the ajax call returns when I console log this.state.items:

```
    Object {items: Array[1]}
          items: Array[1]
            0: Object
              id: "cmkgsrcohfebl5isa79034h8a4"
              start: Object
              summary: "Stuff going down"
```

If I skip the ajax call and create my own state, the mapping works:

```
    state =  { items: [
            { items: { summary: "testing"} },
            { items: { summary: "12"} },
            { items: { summary: "3"} }
          ]};
```

To get this working, however, I change my render-function to:

```
    render(){
            let lista = this.state.items;
            let arr = Object.keys(lista).map(key => lista[key])
            return (
              <div class = "container">
                  {arr.map((item, index) => {
                    const summary = item.items.summary;
                    return (<div key={index}>{summary}</div>);
                  })}
              </div>
            );
          }
```

So maybe it has something to do with the object that this.state.items returns from the ajax call?

Edit2: @Andrea Korinski, you were right! I changed my render function to this, and now it works:

```
          render(){
            let list = this.state.items;
            const arr = (list.items || []).map((item, index) => {
              const summary = item.summary;
              return (<div key={index}>{summary}</div>);
              });
            return (
              <div class = "container">
                  {arr}
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
```

The whole component:

```
    export default class Container extends React.Component{
          calendarID="xxx";
          apiKey="zzz";
          state = {items: []};
          setEvents = (a) => {
            this.setState(a);
          }
          componentDidMount() {
            ajax.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${this.calendarID}/events?fields=items(summary,id,location,start)&key=${this.apiKey}`)
              .end((error, response) => {
                if(!error && response ) {
                  this.setEvents({items: response.body});
                  console.log("success");
                  console.log(this.state.items);
                } else {
                  console.log("Errors: ", error);
                }
              });
          }
          render(){
            let list = this.state.items;
            const irr = (list.items || []).map((item, index) => {
              const summary = item.summary;
              return (<div key={index}>{summary}</div>);
              });
            return (
              <div class = "container">
                  {irr}
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: Maybe you should map not all the keys of your response, but `items` array (i.e. `const arr = (lista.items || []).map((val, index) => ... )` ?

Comment: Can you show what some of the data looks like? also...I would create a constructor and create this.state inside the constructor.

Comment: I think the issue is around the ajax call and componentDidMount(), not with .map

Quick spike on your code *without* the _componentDidMount()_ works fine. [Check here: ](http://codepen.io/gbhasha/pen/akEdAx?editors=1111)

You can directly assign _this.state.events_ to _arr_ varibale. (why do u loop through _Object.keys_ ?)

Comment: Why are you using arrow functions in a class? It's possibly something to do with the value of 'this' in the arrow function.

Comment: @NeilTwist arrow functions are allowed in ES6. there is nothing wrong using arrow functions in a class.

Comment: Still, I don't understand why you are using _*let arr = Object.keys(lista).map(key => lista[key])*_

you could directly assign _this.state.items_ to _arr_

Comment: Galeel, the response from the ajax-call is an object with arrays and objects, and I'm trying to map the right one, items, so that I can access the values of for instance summary, id, and start etc (see my edit). I want to iterate over these items, so that I can print the next calendar events from my google calendar, with info such as summary, id and start etc. But since the response from the ajax-call is an object, and not an array, I figured I had to map the keys for the different items. I'm a beginner, though, and I think I've taken a bit of a large bite here. What better way to learn ;)

Comment: @GaleelBhasha Yes, Arrow functions are fine, but I'm questioning their use: a) in a class, b) when the other functions are defined in the standard style.

Comment: hi @GaleelBhasha, i know this is not related on this topic. But I have a question regarding on tabs swipe... https://codepen.io/gbhasha/pen/gaggRR :), I posted some question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238250/tab-panels-swipe-able-in-mobile-view/40239511#40239511